# nhibernate collection update fk reference in child is becoming null on update

Tags: nhibernate

I have parent and a child, insertion happens just fine ! if I retrieve the parent (along with child collection) and modify values of child and perform session.SaveOrUpdate(Digikeyset), all values gets updated in the child records, however issue is FK column is getting updated to NULL in child.

```
<class name="Digikeyset" table="`digikeyset`" lazy="false">
<id name="Iddigikeyset" column="`iddigikeyset`" type="int">
  <generator class="native" />
 </id>
<property type="string" length="100" name="Mpart" column="`mpart`" />
<property type="int" name="Boardqty" column="`boardqty`" />
<bag name="Fkdigirowset" inverse="false" lazy="false" cascade="all" >
    <key column="`iddigiset`" />
  <one-to-many class="bomorderDal.Digikeyrow,bomorderDal" />
</bag>  </class>

<class name="Digikeyrow" table="`digikeyrow`" lazy="false">
<id name="Iddigikeyrow" column="`iddigikeyrow`" type="int">
  <generator class="native" />
</id>
<property type="Boolean" name="Ispartselected" column="`ispartselected`" />
<property type="Boolean" name="Ispartfound" column="`ispartfound`" />
<many-to-one name="Iddigiset" cascade="save-update" column="`iddigiset`" />
  </class>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the issue, but if you modify values you should Flush not SaveOrUpdate. Save is for new objects, Update is for existing objects that are not attached to the session.

So instead of:

```
session.SaveOrUpdate(Digikeyset)
```

Try:

```
session.Flush()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Had tried this. Finally got the result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion. Had tried with suggested options, but with no luck.

Finally got the result. Removed

```
<many-to-one name="Iddigiset" cascade="save-update" column="`iddigiset`" />
```

from the child and that did the trick. By the way I'm using Nhibernate libraries required for medium-trust environment.